# Debugging PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, debugging

Where is the `Variables Watch`-window in the debugging mode of Window's default PowerShell-IDE `Windows PowerShell ISE` (C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe?

Or how else do you recommend to debug PowerShell code?

Comment: There is no Watch Window in Powershell ISE. You have to hover the variable in the editor window to see its actual value, when a breakpoint is hit. You should consider to use Visual Studio Code and it's Powershell Extension.

Comment: [The PowerShell ISE is no longer in active feature development. As a shipping component of Windows, it continues to be officially supported for security and high-priority servicing fixes. We currently have no plans to remove the ISE from Windows.

There is no support for the ISE in PowerShell v6 and beyond. Users looking for replacement for the ISE should use **Visual Studio Code** with the **PowerShell Extension**.](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell ISE isn't able to do this, personally I find its debugging tools confusing anyway. You should consider using Visual Studio Code, Microsoft's free text editor, it has full support for writing and debugging PowerShell.

1. Download it from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/)
2. Open Extensions from the icon on the left:
   [image]
3. Install the `ms-vscode.powershell` Extension, this adds all the PowerShell features you could need:
   [image]
4. Open your PowerShell script or create a new file, once it's saved as a `.ps1` it will detect is as a PowerShell script and start the tools for you. Or you can manually specify the type from the bottom-right button:
   [image]
5. Write your code, click the Run and Debug icon on the left and click Run and Debug to setup debugging:
   [image]
6. From this point forward, you can press F5 to run your code and start debugging, or click the Run icon at the top-right:
   [image]
7. Add a break-point by clicking just left of the line numbers, it will appear as a red-dot:
   [image]
8. When the debugger hits that point, you can access the variable list on the left, right-click any variable to add it to the watch list:
   [image]